# Wordpress installing supabase and imports

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, api, supabase

I am trying to connect with my Supabase API and following the docs

[Supabase DOCS](https://supabase.com/docs/reference/javascript/installing)

But everytime I write down:

```
import { createClient } from '@supabase/supabase-js'
```

I get an error "import declarations may only appear at top level of a module"

So is it even possible to use the `npm install @supabase/supabase-js` in my child theme and then uploading it?

Or what else is going wrong here?

I tried typing `type="module"` when trying it with the CDN link but still the same error.

Comment: Have you tried to use [PHPSupabase](https://github.com/rafaelwendel/phpsupabase#about-supabase)? I assume that it would fit better your system with Wordpress.

Comment: Have you found the solution?